# PDF/Image viewer with scaling to a calibrated size

Tags: screen, tablet, images, pdf

I'm looking for a way to consistently display raster images or PDFs, so that the image on screen has a calibrated physical size. I.e. I create an image/PDF on a computer with a shape 10cm*10cm and want it to be exactly this size on the tablet's screen. I don't care if I have to measure/calibrate something beforehand, or if the viewer on the device queries e.g. the screen size/ppi and image dpi to do this. I only need this to be accurate for one single device.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Asking for software is off topic. Edited to avoid closure. If you explicitly want software delete this here and ask on [SE.softwarec](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but do read their help before so that it fits there